# Deserializing ObjectResult with declaredType properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deserialization

**Problem**

My API structure is currently being tightly coupled to the external API structure in one class due to the deserialization of one type.

**More details**

Deserializing an [ObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1) from an external API uses the declaredType property with a custom type ErrorDetails including the external API namespace. The deserialization only works if I have the type ErrorDetails in my solution with same exact namespace, otherwise it throws:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
> "x.y.ErrorDetails, x,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" to type
> 'System.Type'. Path 'declaredType', line 1, position 6928.  --->
> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String
> to System.Type.

I'm deserializing with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectResult>(content);
```

**Question**

I thought on trying with `ObjectResult<ErrorDetails>` but that is from NET framework not NET Core 3.1 that my API uses. Any ideas on how to solve this properly?

**Json to be serialized**

```
{
"value":{//this is ErrorDetails
    "stackTrace": "...",
    "errors":{
        "gameUrl":[
            "GameUrl cannot be parsed"
        ]
    },
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "extensions":{
        
    }
},
"formatters":[
    
],
"contentTypes":[
    
],
"declaredType":"x.y.ErrorDetails, x, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
"statusCode":400
}
```

**ErrorDetails in my API with a different namespace not working**

```
namespace m.n
{
    public class ErrorDetails : ProblemDetails //Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
    {
        public ErrorDetails()
        {
        }

        public string StackTrace { get; set; }

        public string InnerException { get; set; }

        public string Identifier { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the json and the full type you're trying to deserialize into?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen done

Answer (score 0):

Based on the serialized Json string, the classes should as below:

```
public class ErrorDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("formatters")]
    public List<object> Formatters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contentTypes")]
    public List<object> ContentTypes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("declaredType")]
    public string DeclaredType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("statusCode")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}
public class Errors
{
    [JsonProperty("gameUrl")]
    public List<string> GameUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Extensions
{
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("stackTrace")]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Errors Errors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extensions")]
    public Extensions Extensions { get; set; }
}
```

Then, user `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method to deserialize the JSON string:

```
        var jsonstring = "{\"value\":{\"stackTrace\":\"...\",\"errors\":{\"gameUrl\":[\"GameUrl cannot be parsed\"]},\"type\":\"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1\",\"title\":\"One or more validation errors occurred.\",\"extensions\":{}},\"formatters\":[],\"contentTypes\":[],\"declaredType\":\"x.y.ErrorDetails, x, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\",\"statusCode\":400}";
        //using Newtonsoft.Json;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorDetails>(jsonstring);
```

the result as below:

[image]